# Kibana 4.0.3 - Simple scripted field not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

I have two fields - `OldValue` and `NewValue` indexed in elasticsearch.

For both these fields :

```
type -> number
analyzed -> false
indexed -> true
```

Now I am trying to add a scripted field called `ChangeInValue` in Kibana as :

```
doc['OldValue'].value - doc['NewValue'].value
```

After adding this script when I go to Discover tab I get:

> Discover: An error occurred with your request. Reset your inputs and try again.

**Note** :

*I have documents in which these fields do not exist*. I think it should set the new field `ChangeInValue` to 0 in such documents. Nevertheless I have tried this :

```
doc['OldValue'].empty ? 0 : doc['OldValue'].value - doc['NewValue'].value
```

But this also throws the same error on the Discover tab.

My problem seems similar to [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/scripted-fields-if-value-exists/23887).

I am using AWS hosted elasticsearch.